# What is wrong with this command - docker volume command

Tags: docker

What is wrong with this command, I didnt see "demo" in the container . Very weird.

```
admin@DESKTOP-LLOK073 MINGW64 ~                                                                               
$ winpty docker container run --name test5 -it -v $(pwd)/demo:/demo alpine sh                                 
/ # cd demo                                                                                                   
sh: cd: can't cd to demo: No such file or directory                                                           
/ # ls                                                                                                        
\Program Files\Git\demo  home                     opt                      sbin                     usr       
bin                      lib                      proc                     srv                      var       
dev                      media                    root                     sys                                
etc                      mnt                      run                      tmp                                
/ #
```

Comment: When running this command on linux it works as expected. Creates demo folders in current dir and /demo in the container. Can't look into a windows version of docker though, but there does not seem to be anything wrong with it when you ask me,

Comment: I see it is wrong, but my question is - what actually happened here ? to my surprise, it created "\Program Files\Git\demo", means the path after : is literally escaped .. got to do something with windows path ssperators ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe here the program took `$(pwd)` and get `C:\Program Files\Git`, then `-v` interprets `$(pwd)/demo:/demo` as `C:\Program Files\Git\demo:\demo`.

Finally, it mounts `C` in the system to `\Program Files\Git\demo` in the container, and ignores everything including and after the second `:`.

Since it looks like that you are using Windows, I recommend that you can just use a Windows version of docker instead of going into MINGW64 and use `winpty`. After installing docker you should be able to launch docker by opening a terminal window (i.e. a Command Prompt or PowerShell, but not PowerShell ISE) and type:

```sh
> docker --version
```

Comment: Why not " PowerShell ISE"

Comment: Hi @Nag Sorry I am not an expert on this, but the [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#test-your-installation) simply states that _Command Prompt or PowerShell, but not PowerShell ISE_.